# make a list of products with partial same product number

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to make an (html) list of products that have the same unique number behind the full stop (`.`). For example, 1.0001 is white bread sold on Monday 2.0001 is white bread sold on Tuesday and so on.

Now I want to make a list that sums of all white bread sold throughout the week. This is what I have so far:

```php
<?php   
  echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'>";  
  echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";  
  echo "<td width='100' align='center'>Produkt</td><td width='100' align='center'>Baklijst</td>";  
  include("dbopen.php");  

  $result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT order_item_name, SUM( product_quantity ) 
     FROM wntl_virtuemart_order_items
     WHERE wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_item_sku REGEXP  '0001$'
     AND order_status =  'U'");  

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['order_item_name'] . "</td>";   
    echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['SUM(product_quantity)'] . "</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";  
  }  
  echo "</table>";  
?>
```

output:

Notice: Undefined index: SUM(product_quantity) in *.php on line 17

Comment: use `like '%.0001'` in your sql and try.

Comment: did already same result..

Comment: Normalise your design and stop using PHP's archaic and long since deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: Also, the `SUM(product_quantity)` error is because that column is not in the DB table. The output of `desc  wntl_virtuemart_order_items` should show the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php   
  echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'>";  
  echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";  
  echo "<td width='100' align='center'>Produkt</td><td width='100' align='center'>Baklijst</td>";  
  include("dbopen.php");  

  $result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT order_item_name, SUM( product_quantity ) AS Sum 
     FROM wntl_virtuemart_order_items
     WHERE wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_item_sku REGEXP  '0001$'
     AND order_status =  'U'");  

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['order_item_name'] . "</td>";   
    echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['Sum'] . "</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";  
  }  
  echo "</table>";  
?>
```

Comment: Please brief what you have changed in the OP's code and don't post code only.

Comment: wouw! this is what i ment but there is only one product in that list i have 40 product :

%.001 til  % .00040

is there a option to get this in one list?
im so greathfull for all help! superb!

Comment: numbers %.0001 - %.00040 i ment

Comment: Ok, sorry!
I simply add an alias in the SQL query to retrieve the results later...

Comment: Ok, so the number after the dot is not constant? could you post some rows?

Comment: yes the number after the dot says what product the nuber before the dot says what day so i have 40 products .0001 .0002 .0003 .0004 and so on

Comment: ok, so if you want all the products you need to remove one of  the WHERE clause...and remain "WHERE  order_status =  'U'"
But why don't you consider to use two different columns to store product number and sell date?

Comment: becorse i want to knoiw how manny white bread i did sel to retailer
now if i make a total i get total of whitebread monday becourse the numbers are uniek i need a sum on whitebread %.0001 not a sum on mondaywhitebread 1.0001
im dutch so i hope my answer is clear..

Comment: So removing "wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_item_sku REGEXP  '0001$'" do the job?

Comment: i get a total of all products deliverd on monday (i assume) its says whitebreadmonday 327 (i have sold 8) no list of other products

Comment: so i think i need something like:

WHERE wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_item_sku REGEXP  '0001$' - '00040$'

Comment: you can do it in a subquery in mysql, but I still think that this is a wrong approach...use two (or more) columns and will be all easier.

Comment: the way i see it you have to break the product number a part so u can use the number behind the dot. the number behind the dot is leading to the product

Comment: i did copy paste for every product this :
$result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT order_item_name, SUM( product_quantity ) AS Sum 
     FROM wntl_virtuemart_order_items
     WHERE wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_item_sku REGEXP  '0002$'
     AND order_status =  'U'");  

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['order_item_name'] . "</td>";   
    echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['Sum'] . "</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";  
  }

gives the wanted result